# How to handle http stream responses from within a Substrate offchain worker?

Tags: substrate

Starting from the Substrate's Offchain Worker recipe that leverages the Substrate http module, I'm trying to handle http responses that are delivered as streams (basically interfacing a pubsub mechanism with a chain through a custom pallet).

Non-stream responses are perfectly handled as-is and reflecting them on-chain with signed transactions is working for me, as advertised in the doc.

However, when the responses are streams (meaning the http requests are never completed), I can only see the stream data logs in my terminal when I shut down the Substrate node. Trying to reflect each received chunk as a signed transaction doesn't work either: I can also see my logs only on node shut down, and the transaction is never sent (which makes sense since the node is down).

Is there an existing pattern for this use case? Is there a way to get the stream observed in background (not in the offchain worker runtime)?

Actually, would it be a good practice to keep the worker instance running ad vitam for this http request? (knowing that in my configuration the http request is sent only once, via a scheme of command queue - in the pallet storage - that gets cleaned at each block import).